# Wpf, keeping selection in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, selection

Let's say I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Entity> Entities;
    public int SelectedEntityId { get; set; }
}
```

And the following XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedValuePath="Id" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEntityId}" />
```

Sometimes, there's a need to refresh `Entities` from database. In such case I'd like to keep the selection in the combo box (if the item with selected Id still exists in the `Entities`, of course). How can I do that?

To warn, this solution **does not** work:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    int oldId = SelectedEntityId;

    repository.Entities.Get()
        .OrderBy(e => e.Name)
        .ToObservableCollection(Entities); // My extension

    SelectedEntityId = oldId;
    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEntityId");
}
```

Comment: Is there any async operation involved here?

Comment: It SHOULD work in general case - so it's all down to what "your extension" called `ToObservableCollection(...)` does. Could you please share some code?

Comment: @KingKing: There is no asynchronous code in my project whatsoever.

Comment: @Grx70 Not much - it clears the collection and adds elements from the query, one by one. I can include the code if you really want to, but there's no magic there.

Comment: not sure what's wrong but I've just made a simple demo and it works fine, I've just tested against a simple local list but I don't think it matters the database here.

Comment: try adding issynchronizedwithcurrentitem=true on the combobox

Comment: @Spook I think that there is a problem with a reffrences, after the referesh done. I gues that they are new. Try to base your logic on a SelectedIndex property of a ComboBox.